# Entry into Schengen state before visa is valid

Tags: visas, schengen

My Schengen visa is valid from 5 July, but I need to get into France on the 28th of June.

Will I be able to?

Comment: No. If you have flight ticket for 5th of July, will the airline allow you to board the plane on the 28th of June ? What made you think that the border officer will allow you to enter ?

Comment: No.  If you need to report a change of circumstances, you should contact the post that issued your Schengen.

Comment: Thank you DumbCoder! Thought maybe I can just opt for a tourist visa at the air port in France instead of going through the whole application process at the embassy again.

Comment: Thanks Gayfot. Don't have enough time. One week to go.

Comment: @Carlen: There **is no such thing** as "tourist visa at the airport" for the Schengen area! If you need a visa it has to be applied for (and issued) before traveling.

Comment: Nice tot talk to so many experienced travellers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Carlen, you'll suddenly find yourself with lots of free time on the 28th :)  Best to get started now

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not be able to. You will almost certainly be denied boarding by your airline and, if you do somehow make it to the port of entry, you would be refused entry, detained and forced to return to your point of origin at the earliest opportunity.

And since you have a Schengen visa, it also means you actually *require* one to enter and therefore absolutely need to go through the whole application process.

For completeness, note that there are some exceptions, like seamen *en route* to their ship and members of an EU citizens family, who might be afforded the possibility to apply for a visa at the border. But that's not an option for regular travellers.